# Is it possible to get equality for all $n$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

I define a recurrence relation as follow:

$$ω_{n+1}=f(ω_{n})$$ for some function $f$.

Assume that $f:ℝ→ℝ$ is a continuous, strictly increasing (so it is bijective) and a contraction function. Then $(ω_{n})$  converges to the fixed point of $f$, i.e., $ω_{n}$→$x$ with $f(x)=x$ and this is the only type of solutions for the above recurrence equation. Now, assume we know that $ω_{n}=a_{n}$ (with $a_{n+1}=f(a_{n}$)) for some values of $n$ (the two sequences are equal without any law) where $a_{n}$ is a known sequence.

My **question** is: Can we deduce that $ω_{n}=a_{n}$ for all $n$.

Comment: Only if we know $a_{n+1}=f(a_n)$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Yes, we have that equation for some values of $n$. Do you have a proof for that.

Comment: What does 'equal without any order' mean?

Comment: @E.James I have no clue what comes next after 7. Did you mean primes for some reason? What does this have to do with order?

Comment: @CalvinKhor: I mean that ther are equal for $n=2,3,5,7,...$ and other values without any law.

Comment: So you mean "$a_n = \omega_n$" for $n$ prime, and you don't claim anything about other values of $a_n$?

Comment: You are not explaining well. I hope you find someone who understands

Comment: @CalvinKhor: We know only that the sequences are equal for some $n$.

Comment: And somehow 2,3,5, and 7 are special? Regardless, user14168 gave you an answer but you somehow don't agree with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments it is not enough, for instance if you take $a_n$ defined as follow : $a_{2n}$ = $\omega_{2n}$ and $ a_{2n+1} = 0$ then your premises will be verified but (unless $(\omega)$ is null after a certain $n$) the two sequences are not equal.

Edit : You said in the comments that $(a_n)$ also verifies the property $a_{n+1} = f(a_n)$, now you can simply start at the smallest $n_0$ for which they are equal and prove by induction that : $\forall n \geq n_0 , a_n = \omega_n$. To prove it for $n < n_0$ you will at least need to assume $f$ is an injection.

Comment: @ user14168:  I assume that the two sequences are equal without any order.

Comment: @E.James From what you are saying you don't have enough informations to conclude the sequences are equal, coming with a counter-example is easy.